# Macports' dropping of privileges causing Xcode licence problems

Tags: xcode, licensing, sudo, macports, privileges

I am trying to install some ports using Macports on OS X but as soon as the installation tries to invoke the C compiler I get:

> Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.

Context:

- I have run `sudo xcodebuild -license` and successfully agreed to the
  licence however when I run `xcodebuild -license` I get the same error
  as above.
- I am running Macports in sudo: `sudo port install ghostscript` but
  Macports seems to drop the privileges during the installation. (Also tried using the terminal as root user but that didn't seem to help either.)

Therefore, I am seeing two options: either managing to somehow agree to the licence at my user level, or forcing Macports to retain the privileges. But so far didn't manage to do any of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

License acceptance is stored in

- /Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist,
- ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist (MacPorts copies this file from your home on startup to support older Xcode releases that required per-user acceptance), or
- ~macports/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist

Try moving these files aside if they exist and re-do the license acceptance using `sudo xcodebuild -license`. Try also cleaning out `/var/folders/zz`, the Xcode command line tools use this to cache some data that may cause this problem. If that doesn't help, check file permissions on these files (at least the first one should be `-rw-r--r--`, i.e. readable by everyone).

There is a way to make MacPorts build as root rather than dropping privileges, but you shouldn't do that unless absolutely necessary. The privilege separation is a safety feature to avoid misbehaving ports from wreaking havoc on your system.

Comment: Tried all of the suggestions but no luck :(
I think as this stage of desperation I am ready to give MacPorts full privileges.
Thanks for your help

Comment: You can set `macportsuser` to `root` in `macports.conf`, but as I said, it's a *REALLY* bad idea. Rather, try invoking clang as `macports` with dtruss to produce more debugging information, e.g. `echo "int main() {}" | sudo dtruss -f sudo -u macports clang -x c -` and provide the output.

Comment: Sorry for not looking into this earlier. Will try it out and get back.

Comment: I have edited the conf file as follows but nothing seems to have changed (I might be missing something very basic). Here is how the relevant part of the conf file looks like: 

`# User to run operations as when MacPorts drops privileges.[newline]
#macportsuser         macports[newline]
root                                 macports[newline]
`
I have also run the given command but the trace is too long so it is posted [here](http://pastebin.ca/3003542).

Comment: I would blow away `/var/folders/fs/_r5hy4ms0zg6lgj3fnnxtdmh0000gp` and re-run the license acceptance, since the `xcrun_db` file there is sometimes used to cache license acceptance. For the configuration change, you need to put `macportsuser root` on a line of its own in the configuration file.

Comment: Sorry didn't try the first part but finally managed to install xfig as root!
Many thanks for your help!